# Unable to build Xcode project on circleCi

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, circleci, fastlane

I'm using cocoapods v1.0.1. My build is successful in Xcode 7.2.1 but when I push the changes to git it fails on circleci.com.

> error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

I have tried every possible ways using this link and similar links but no success at all.

Already tried this link: [Error:"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock..." after installing RestKit with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following into your circle.yml file:

```
dependencies:
  override:
    - pod install
```

https://discuss.circleci.com/t/the-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock/5537