# Ionic 3 - xcode error with cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, cocoapods, ionic3

I try to build an ionic 3 app with push notification and I have some problem with iOS deployment.

I have this 3 error in xcode :

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I have try a lot of solution I found on internet :

- use command "pod install", "pod update"
- delete and install CocoaPods
- update CocoaPods
- Delete "Pods" folder, "Podfile.lock" and "Podfile" and run "pod install" command.
- Remove libPods-myApp.a from Link Binary From Librairies.

But nothing is effective...

I really don't know what I have to do.

My Podfile :

```
# DO NOT MODIFY -- auto-generated by Apache Cordova
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'MyProject' do
    project 'MyProject.xcodeproj'
    pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging', '~> 1.2.0'
    pod 'GGLInstanceID', '~> 1.2.1'
end
```

My Podfile.lock :

```
PODS:
  - GGLInstanceID (1.2.1)
  - GoogleCloudMessaging (1.2.0):
    - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleIPhoneUtilities (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
  - GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)
  - GoogleIPhoneUtilities (1.2.1):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.0)
    - GoogleUtilities (~> 1.0)
  - GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
  - GoogleUtilities (1.3.2):
    - GoogleSymbolUtilities (~> 1.1)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - GGLInstanceID (~> 1.2.1)
  - GoogleCloudMessaging (~> 1.2.0)

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  GGLInstanceID: 4a317044f744281b82cd03015f379899f277cad3
  GoogleCloudMessaging: f37ea14dd0f41d4d889c10b5559dd35bbfd9ac26
  GoogleInterchangeUtilities: d5bc4d88d5b661ab72f9d70c58d02ca8c27ad1f7
  GoogleIPhoneUtilities: 63f25e93a3ddcb66884d182aab3a660d98f1479b
  GoogleSymbolUtilities: 631ee17048aa5e9ab133470d768ea997a5ef9b96
  GoogleUtilities: 8bbc733218aad26306f9d4a253823986110e3358

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 0ff66d442dc6f28bf0fbc7a6b12af811ecc9a43c

COCOAPODS: 1.2.1
```

**UPDATE**

My [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock :

```
diff "${PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH}/Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I really need help please. :(

**UPDATE**

I have modify my [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock to this :

```
diff "${SRCROOT}/Podfile.lock" "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

My tree errors are disapear but I have this new error :

```
 Module 'FirebaseInstanceID' not found
```

[image]

I don't know why. I tried to run `pod install` but no difference.

Comment: You tried all of this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/errorthe-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-res

Comment: Yes I do. But nothing different.

Comment: @pivet are you deemed to use push-notification or you can give a try of One-Signal which takes care of the cocoapods installation by itself

Comment: did you solved this isse? I am also facing same problem?

Comment: I also have the same issue.  Any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: Are you opening Workspace or Project when building?

Comment: So, try this:

-> Open Workspace
-> Delete all libs from build settings and all related Cocoapods references, included CP something
-> Close workspace
-> Remove Workspace
-> Remove Pods folder
-> Remove Podfile.lock
-> Pod update

Comment: Did you mean all libs from "build phases" ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for mislead

Comment: Try this:

rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/"
pod update

Comment: Haven't a "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods" folder.

Comment: Which version of Cocoapods you have?

type this on terminal:
pod --version

Comment: I use version 1.2.1. But it's ok, I just mistaked for the command. I ran it but nothing better; ^^'

Comment: So try to update:

sudo gem install cocoapods

And repeat all those steps i mentioned before.

Comment: Ionic 2 isn't a problem ? Do you think I have to use Ionic 3 ?

Comment: I mean update Cocoapods, not ionic. Don't know if that ionic version has problems, just wanted to make sure you are using latest version of cocoapods.

Comment: I keep my errors. I really don't understand.. But thanks for your help

Comment: do you use Source Control? Try to committ everything and checkout the project again, then pod install after that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149396/discussion-between-ppinho-and-v-pivet).

Answer (score 2):

Please check the path of the xcode project

> project 'MyProject.xcodeproj'

Does your podfile and the 'MyProject.xcodeproj' are located on the same directory ? If so you can try removing the ligne above from your podfile

Answer (score 2):

Open up terminal and run

```
pod deintegrate
```

This will remove all connections of pods and your project.

Then you can run

```
pod install
```