# Ionic 3 - FirebaseInstanceID not found

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, ionic2

I try to build an Ionic 3 app with push notification on iOS.

Refeer to this post : 
[Ionic 3 - xcode error with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059173/ionic-3-xcode-error-with-cocoapods)

I had tree errors :

```
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
```

I tried to solve it buy this modification in my [CP] Check Pods Manifest.lock to this :

```
diff "${SRCROOT}/Podfile.lock" "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    # print error to STDERR
    echo "error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation." >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I think it works. But now, I have a new error in xCode after try to run on my device :

```
 Module 'FirebaseInstanceID' not found
```

I tried to run pod install again but no difference. I tried to modify my podfile like this ...

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyProject' do
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Fi
```

But I keep my error. Someone have a solution to solve this ?

Comment: Exactly same issue. Can't find a way out....

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue, and [this solution](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1825#issuecomment-359155007) worked for me:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Inside platforms/ios

```
pod install --verbose
```

Go to platforms/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-proj

Copy all the content of the files:

```
Pods-proj.debug.xconfig
Pods-proj.release.xconfig
```

And put them in their equivalents in platforms/ios

Cleaning and Building was then successful in Xcode.

It looks like they weren't being found or properly referenced somehow in the top-level files.

Comment: I didn't need to copy the content of the files, it worked after pod install, thankyou

Answer (score 3):

I surely faced this problem when running my ionic3 application on ios device, here is what you may need to do to get it working.
Run `cd platforms/ios
         pod install`
Or check out this link for additional help. 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md