# could not find compatible versions for pod

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods

I am new in IOS development and git. I am having a problem after merging my local repo to the dev repo. After merging when I build the project I get an error in the Xcode that says, **"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation."**

[Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW8Tc.png)

I searched about this and tried the usual solution reinstalling the pods. But executing

```
pod install
```

I get another error in terminal that says

[Terminal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhsGH.png)

At this point I tried deleting the files associated with the "FTPopOverMenu" pod and reinstalling with *pod install*. The error doesn't go away. Also, I tried solving it in this way - [Error:“The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock…” after installing RestKit with cocoapods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878202/9238916)

But both error in the Xcode and in the terminal still remains. I'm new to IOS and Git. I really don't understand what is really happening here.

Comment: have you define a version for FTPopOverMenu in your pod file so check it(pod 'FTPopOverMenu', '~> 1.3')  if it is not match with cocoa pod version or else try this "pod deintegrate" and "pod install" and "pod update" if any issue so let me know

Comment: I did the first-bit _try this `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`_ but the same error came up when I executed the `pod install`. I don't know what happened but the `pod update` fixed it. After deintigrating the `pod update` installed all the pods. No more pod error though. Thanks, man.

Comment: your problem resolved ? or not

Comment: resolved. Thanks. :D

Comment: as per my guess you are working on an old project means which is already developed in Xcode 8 series and now you are working with latest Xcode and you have updated the code accordingly. and can i post my answer so it might help to other user ?

Comment: your guess is right. post your answer.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

As per my guess you are working on an old project means which is already developed in Xcode 8 series and now you are working with latest Xcode and you have updated the code accordingly.

So just do the below steps:

1. "pod deintegrate"
2. "pod install"
3. "pod update" (if it is necessary so do it else if you have all latest pod so don't use it.)

It will remove all old cocoapods traces.

**OR Alternate way to do it (Temp Work Around)**

- Remove that cocoa pod temporary, after all your work finish add to your project and give a try cause in my case it is the only work around i have that worked.

Comment: I did a combo between your answer and @Sardorbek Rkh

Answer (score 53):

In my case pod repos were outdated, solved with `pod repo update`

Comment: What if it's not helping?

Comment: this worked for me. After that I could run `pod install`

Answer (score 38):

if @Ravi Panchal's answer can't solve your problem, it may be your pod repo is out dated

Solution:

```
pod install --repo-update
```

Answer (score 28):

First, check your Podfile.lock and make sure no conflict with the spec constraints.

I encounter this issue with strange pod dependency, and solve it by

`1. remove Podfile.lock`

`2. pod install` again

It just work like magic. I think it is a bug that cocoapods cannot solve this kind of constraints in Podfile.lock. Remove the old Podfile.lock can make it apply the new rule easily.

Answer (score 10):

In .podfile

changed the iOS version

> platform :ios, '13.0' // Warning change by your desired

It worked

Answer (score 7):

please check your podfile and update the platform to the appropriate version number

`platform :ios, '11.0'`

Comment: In my case that was the trick because I updated to Flutter 3.3 and it's not compatible with iOS 10. Thx.

Answer (score 5):

In my case it worked after I changed iOS version from 8.0 to 9.0 in Target (not Project) settings >> General >> Deployment Info

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with `FIRMessaging` from `cocoapods`. I solved the issue by doing like following steps

1. Remove `FTPopOverMenu` from your `podfile` which can find in your project folder.
2. Open terminal and run `pod install`. You can see in terminal that `FTPopOverMenu` will be removing from your pods.
3. Now, again open your `podfile` and write this `pod 'FTPopOverMenu'`. Run `pod install` in terminal.

The error will go away from terminal.

Comment: I followed the solution @ravi.p gave. I tried to solve it in this way, but every time I did `pod install` the same error occurred.

Comment: have you removed FTPopOverMenu from your podfile before installing

Comment: yes. But [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhsGH.png) was still there. `pod deintegrate` removed all cocoapods traces. Then `pod update` installed everything again. `pod install` didn't work. I have had a similar problem with **JVFloatLabeledTextField** and I removed the JVFloatLabeledTextField Folder from the Pods in my project navigator and uninstalled it with `pod install`. But this time `pod install` was showing the same error. Even after doing deintegrate.

Answer (score 2):

if you are facing this error in Flutter `CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod`

1. increase your minimum deployments
2. `cd ios` and then `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`
3. `flutter build ios`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed by a change to dynamic pod version.

And delete file Podfile.lock

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the line below in your Podfile. Please make sure it is commented. it works for me.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer regarding this in the thread already. But this time my scenario was different. My co-worker accidentally updated the cocoa version from the stable to a beta version, while I was using the lower stable version. I wasn't interested using the beta version, so I didn't update.

As deleting `podfile.lock` is dangerous which leads to removing the Cocoapods traces, I just opened `podfile.lock` in editors like Sublime Text, and downgraded the pod which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the iOS Deployment Target, make it 11.0 and then do

```
pod install
```

and it will be fixed