# Right way to add Charts with cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, charts, cocoapods

Charts suggested us to install them with cocoapods without specifying release tag:
pod 'Charts'
and this is means that we are working with the master / trunk branch, right?
So what is about potential risks of the inability of the existing Application with the last changes in Charts? How can I add Charts with specifying the concrete version?

P.S. specifying tag neither

```
pod 'Charts', '4.0.1'
```

nor

```
  pod 'Charts', :git => 'https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git', :tag => '4.0.1'
```

doesn't help, and brings us the error:

```
% pod update
...
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Charts":
  In Podfile:
    Charts (= 4.0.1)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Charts (= 4.0.1)`.

You have either:
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [could not find compatible versions for pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638059/could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod)

Comment: Honey, unfortunately, no.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With help of Scott Thompson, I've found that

```
pod 'Charts', '3.6.0'
```

is worked and there are no error at build time! So, I think this is the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Looking in GitHub, it appears that their tags have a "v" at the front of the version number.  I would change your versioned attempt to be:

```
pod 'Charts', :git => 'https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts.git', :tag => 'v4.0.1'
```

Note I've changed `4.0.1` to `v4.0.1` to match the tag name on GitHub.

Comment: Scott, big thanks for paying my attention on the tag  label! Your answer solves the pod installation, but unexpectedly project can't build because of the Charts error - "No such module 'Algorithms'".