# Automatically run pod install command on "The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock" error

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

I was wandering if there is a way to make Xcode run the command "`pod install`" automatically, when the `"The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation."` error happens. Im tired of doing it manually every time.

PS.
Here is the guide from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/running-custom-scripts-during-a-build?changes=_8), but I crash on the:

> 6. In the Shell text field, enter your script code.

Because I don't know what exaclty I should write as the script code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried this script ?? https://gist.github.com/stephanecopin/a52503b85bf23d3ab3a34610ecd2c9b3

Comment: Perhaps use `pod update` instead of `pod install`

Comment: Instead of creating a script, you should rather ask yourself why it happens so often. This error should really be rare. So it's something with your workflow / the way you include pods in podfile that triggers this. As for the error itself, it doesn't have 1 solution. It has a few reasons, and each requires a different solution. See this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21366549/error-the-sandbox-is-not-in-sync-with-the-podfile-lock-after-installing-re
So again, concentrate on eliminating the cause of the error, not trying to work around it.

Comment: It happens because I switch between branches that have different setup, so it's okay really. I just want it to happen automatically