# Install from pod spec file instead of Podfile

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods

Do I have to copy my dependencies from the Kit.podspec to a Podfile, or is there some other way I use the command line tool to get all the dependencies from the .podspec file?

Answer (score 0):

If `Kit` (assuming `Kit.podspec` is for a pod named `Kit`) is already in your `Podfile` then its dependencies will be resolved by Cocoapods in any case.

If you're looking to get *just* the dependencies from `Kit` you can use the [podspec directive](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#podspec) in your `Podfile`.

You can read more related stuff [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1615) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351086/how-to-update-a-single-pod-without-touching-other-dependencies).